# Why .query() function not working on Django ORM query?

Tags: python, django, database

As I already know that using `.query.__str__()` , we can get sql equivalent query from Django ORM query.

e.g : `Employees.objects.filter(id = int(id)).query.__str__()`

Above code working well & I am able to get sql equivalent query 
but when I am using same on below query I am getting error like below.

```
Employees.objects.filter(id = int(id)).first().query.__str__()
AttributeError: 'Employees' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Why now I am getting error, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`.first()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) does *not* return a `QuerySet`, it returns a model object. The query is evaluated eagerly.

You can inspect the last query that Django made with:

```
from django.db import connection
print(connection.queries[-1:])
```

That being said, in essence a `some_queryset.first()` is often the same query as `some_queryset`, except that it will limit the queryset.

> **Note**: Please do *not* use `.__str__`, you can use `str(my_queryset.query)`, or just `print(my_queryset.query)`.

Comment: Thanks ! Above explanation clear my doubts & solved my problem !